# Inserting Opencart login check/force into JS funtion

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart2.x

I have an HTML form inside a very customised Opencart v2.3.0.2 site.

Onsubmit, the form executes two JS functions the following functions

1)myFunction2()adds a product and

2)myFunction()
 submits the form data,

while routing to (`action="index.php?route=checkout/checkout"`)

I need to force the user to login if they are not already logged in before these two functions execute. So, I would want to add another JS function that forces login before executing the next two JS functions. Maybe there is an easier way.

Opencarts built-in function for checking if a user is logged is `$data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();`

Form Submit

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><a id="addtocart" onclick="myFunction2(); myFunction()">Continue to Checkout</a></button>
```

JS Functions

```
function myFunction2() {  //adds product to cart............

    $.get( "index.php?route=checkout/cart/addToCart&product_id=30", function( data ) {
    $( "#myForm" ).addClass( "product-added" ); 
   });

}

function myFunction() {  //submits form option with associated variables.........

    if($( "#myForm" ).hasClass( "product-added" )){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }

}
```

So, Ideally to create a third JS function that executes first and checks if the user is logged. If user is logged continues with the second and third functions. If user is not logged "popup" with a login request, then once logged executes the second and third functions to checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to simply disable the button if the user isn't logged in?

```
<?php $enabled_button = $logged == true ? "" : "disabled readonly"; ?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" <?php echo $enabled_button; ?>><a id="addtocart" onclick="myFunction2(); myFunction()" <?php echo $enabled_button; ?>>Continue to Checkout</a></button>
```

Assuming that `$logged` is set properly by the controller, the expression will `echo` "disabled" & "readonly" values into the HTML element if the user is not logged in.

Alternatively, you can just add an `if` statement to either show the button or show a login button:

```
<?php if($logged) { ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><a id="addtocart" onclick="myFunction2(); myFunction()">Continue to Checkout</a></button>
<?php } else { ?>
    <button type="submit" class=btn btn-success btn-lg"><a id="login" onclick="yourLoginFunction">Login</a></button>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is an option I never considered and certainly one to look into.